# "practitioners' community" or "practitioners community"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I would say the first is the correct one (with apostrophe), but I see the other one much more.

Don't know if it is relevant, but I'm a British English user.

Answer (score 1):

Stan Rogers has got the right answer but the wrong reasoning.

**practitioners'** is correct because what's being refered to is *their* community, so there's a possessive **'s** to be added. But because the subject is already plural, the actual *s* doesn't get written. Nor, incidentally, does it get pronounced in this situation, but pronunciation of the possessive *s* is independent of whether it's written or not.

**practitioner's** applies with a *single* practitioner for anything of his, including *his community*

**practitioners** is invalid with *no* possessive apostrophe, because all you're left with is a plural noun. That can't be used as a modifier to anything, including communities. You can have a *dog trainer*, where the 'noun' *dog* modifies *trainer*. But you can't have a *dogs trainer*.

Comment: Your reasoning is *identical* to mine, it's merely phrased differently.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this specific phrase, so not sure if context would alter the question. Grammatically both can be correct.  You can have a community of practitioners that they themselves do not own, in which case the second choice would be correct.

Comment: So you're saying @Stan Rogers is wrong?

Comment: Well technically speaking I'm sure no practioners actually *own* any communities. They're probably what we in the UK call *General Practitioners* (i.e. - doctors working in their local surgey rather than within a hospital). Usually they're in *Group Practices* where several doctors serve the local community, in which case #1 applies. Sometimes there's only *one* GP, in which case he works in his own **Practitioner's Surgery**. OP's #2 is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The ess-apostrophe version is correct if it is equivalent to *community of practitioners* or *community to which the practitioners belong* (and it's difficult for me to imagine how it wouldn't be with a plural *practitioners* unless the host sentence is very convoluted).

If it is equivalent to *the community to which the practitioner belongs*, then it would be *practitioner's community*.

I've tried to imagine a sentence where there would be no apostrophe, but everything I can think of would require a comma between *practitioners* and *community*.

Answer (score 0):

Context is relevant. "practitioners community" means a community of practitioners, whereas "practitioners' community" means a specific community to which the practitioners belong, implying there may be multiple communities or a larger community beyond the one being discussed. The sentence structure and your intent should guide you to the correct usage.

I disagree with @FumbleFingers about the "dogs trainer". Just because it isn't contemporary language doesn't mean it is invalid. A "dog trainer" may work with a single dog at a time while a "dogs trainer" will work with a group. "dogs' trainer" would refer to a solitary trainer that worked with a specific group of dogs. Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are grammatically correct.  The difference between them is that *practitioners'* is a possessive noun and *practitioners* is a plural noun modifier.  I found [this exchange](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00009.htm) on plural noun modifiers that has some interesting quotes from *Quirk et al., A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Longman*.

In short, the doubt about the validity of form #2 comes from a rule in the past that noun modifiers had to be singular (*apple tree*, *vegetable soup*, *rubber chicken*) but today this is not an absolute and there are many examples of plural noun modifiers in everyday use, for example, *parts departments*, *schools superintendents* and *options markets*.

Quirk lists the following situations where a plural modifier may be used:

> 1. the singular form might lead to ambiguity
>      an Arts degree (a degree in the
>      humanities) as opposed to an art
>      degree (a degree in fine art)
> 2. there is no singular form of a noun (in pluralia tantum)
>      a customs officer
> 3. there is a need to denote variety
>      a soft drinks manufacturer [but] a
>      car manufacturer
> 4. a topical issue comes forth, often in newspaper stories. Quirk cites
>      examples of Watergate reporting from
>      newspapers:
>      the tapes issue
>      the tapes compromise
>      the Watergate tapes affair
>      the White House tapes mystery and other examples, including jobs cut.